How can I add policy check to my livewire Volt::route('/product/{id}')?
I am wondering if I can add a policy check to my Volt::route(). I know I can add
$this->authorize('view', $product);

in my mount() method, but I think its cleaner to have it in route files.
Volt::route('/product/{id}', 'pages.shop.single-product-page')
  ->name('single-product-page');

I know there is a can() method but I have no clue how to pass the product as param to my can() check.
ProductPolicy:
   /**
     * Determine whether the user can view the model.
     */
    public function view(User $user, Product $product): bool
    {
        return $user->tenant->id == $product->tenant->id;
    }

Thanks
!! UPDATED !!
I tried
    Volt::route('/mok-shop/product/{product}', 'pages.shop.single-product-page')
        ->name('single-product-page')
        ->middleware('can:view,product');

However this returns 403 with Gate check
view [▼
  "ability" => "view"
  "result" => null
  "user" => "01bf0839-71ab-3c0b-8fbb-389448de83b5"
  "arguments" => "[0 => 20c5c5c5-3ad0-381d-9e1e-1b6f08ad9334]"
]

I forgot to say my Product Model uses UUID as primary key type
$table->uuid('id')->primary();

and my Product Model has
    public function getRouteKeyName(): string
    {
        return 'id';
    }

    protected $keyType = 'string';


You can do this via a middleware. Laravel uses implicit binding to automatically resolve Eloquent models defined in routes or controller actions whose type-hinted variable names match a route segment name. So the resolved model is passed to the policy method:
Volt::route('/product/{product}', 'pages.shop.single-product-page')->name('single-product-page')->middleware('can:view,product');

You can also use the helper can method:
Volt::route('/product/{product}', 'pages.shop.single-product-page')->name('single-product-page')->can('view','product');

For policy methods that do not require a model instance you can do:
use App\Models\Product;
     
Volt::route('/product/{product}', 'pages.shop.single-product-page')->name('single-product-page')->can('view', Product::class);

Laravel Docs

Thanks for your fast reply. I tried your solutions, however none of them worked. I have updated my question with the Gate result and more information about my model. Appreciate your support, thanks!

@pa2Codes I have the same problem, did you solved it? Authorize sends uuid as string in models array not User model

@MozzieMD Sadly no satisfying solution to this problem. So I added the policy checks in my Volt Component for now.
